# Being able to log a Active Directory user in without access to our wifi?

Tags: vpn, active-directory

Apologies as this is not exactly my field but I will do my best to explain.

I have a coworker who has a laptop and her user for that laptop is tied to our companies Active Directory.  She has mostly worked in the office and so has been on company wifi.  Two weeks ago she was sent to a customer, opened her laptop and could not login with the error "We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available.  Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again.  If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential."  When we tried having her sign out, connecting to my phones hotspot and logging in, same error.

I thought then she would just have to connect to our VPN, but the login Wifi menu does not show the VPN that she has configured so it doesn't seem like we can just put her on any wifi and then connect to the VPN and then have her attempt to login to the computer.

The way our business operates includes many service calls so I don't think it makes sense to have her user as a active directory if it requires her to be on the VPN just to login to her computer - many places we work in are heavy metal factory areas where there is no internet.

What are my options to rectifying this?  Can I convert her account to a local account?  Can I change some policy on the active directory side of things to make her not have to have a connection to login to her own computer?  I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Ensure the GPO tied to the machine is NOT configured like this: https://techexpert.tips/windows/gpo-disable-cached-account-logon/. Then ensure the machine is connected to the network with direct access to AD/domain controllers, have the person sign in (sign out and then back in if needed), wait for the desktop to fully load, then sign out again, disconnect the machine from the network, then have the user try to sign on again. Should be good-to-go moving forward with the cached credential(s).

Comment: Make sure VPN is configured correctly and use any private Wireless anywhere. It works for us.

Comment: @John what would constitute having the VPN correctly configured?  Can you recommend a guide or outline the gist?

Comment: You need to make sure Wireless is set to Private and not Public.  Then turn on Logging, try to connect and see what the log says.